# BIRT display data of groupped by record

Tags: birt, hierarchical-data

In BIRT 3.7.1 I have a table with 1 level hierachical data.
So records have a unique number (key) and a parent field which refers to a key in the dataset. For top level records the parent field is null.

```
 ---+------------+-------------+-----------+
|   |   Key      |   Parent    | Fields... |
+---+------------+-------------+-----------+
| 1 |     100    |             |   INFO    |
| 2 |     101    |        100  |   INFO    |
| 3 |     102    |        100  |   INFO    |
+---+------------+-------------+-----------+
```

When I add a group on the parent field, BIRT will display the top level record (100) in a group with all records where parent is null and all group elements in a group under the label of the parent:

```
 ---+------------+-------------+-----------+
|   |   Key      |   Parent    | Fields... |
+---+------------+-------------+-----------+
|   |            |             |           | <= group header
+---+------------+-------------+-----------+
| 1 |     100    |             |   INFO    |
+---+------------+-------------+-----------+
|   |     100    |             |           | <= group header
+---+------------+-------------+-----------+
| 2 |     101    |        100  |   INFO    |
| 3 |     102    |        100  |   INFO    |
+---+------------+-------------+-----------+
```

I would like to display information about the top level record (i.e. 'parent' record) in the group header.

Is this possible? I know you can use things like row.__rownum and that you can refer to the dataSet or the row in a table data binding. Also you can use rows[0]['fieldName'] if you want to link datasets.

Is there a way to use this info to get to the data of the top level record?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One possible approach (there may be more elegant solutions!) is based on scripting. In the onFetch event, you could add the record to a dictionary (a report variable) using the Key column as the index.

To be precise, you cannot use the record directly AFAIK; instead you have to copy its values.

Let's assume your report variable is named "rowDict".

In the beforeOpen event of the DataSet, you initialize rowDict

```
vars["rowDict"] = new java.lang.HashMap();
```

In the onFetch event of the DataSet, you add the current record's data to rowDict:

```
var rec = new java.lang.HashMap();
rec.put("Info1", row["Info1"]);
// ... and so on for the other columns
vars["rowDict"].put(row["Key"], rec);
```

In the header row, you can access this data using a syntax like

```
vars["rowDict"].get(row["Parent"]).get("Info1")
```

Note that in the header row of a group, row refers to the first record inside this group.

I think the BIRT layout you show in the question isn't quite accurate; you probably moved the data item "Parent" from the "Parent" column to the "Key" column of the Table layout item.

Depending on the database you use, you could also use SQL to solve this problem - which could even be faster, but requires more thinking.

Note: The code is untested, but you get the idea...

Answer (score 0):

I think the easiest approach is to create an aggregation for each field to be displayed:

Right click in the group header row -> Insert -> aggregation.  Select a field as expression, set "First" as aggregate function, "String" or whatever as datatype  and use of course "group on" property on the parent group.

Comment: I don't think this approach is going to work. E.g. this will show the INFO of id 101 in the group header for parent id 100.